# cannot detect two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var exercise= [ 
     ['What is the first name of our professor in this course?', 'cecilia'],
     ['What is the last name of our prof in this coursrs?', 'chan'],
     ['Which language is the most popular one in the world?', 'javascript']
]; 

var player_ans;
var correct_num=0;
for(var i=0; i<exercise.length; i++){
     player_ans= prompt(exercise[i][0]);  
     if(player_ans.toLowerCase === exercise[i][1]){ 
        correct_num+= 1; 
     }
}
document.write('The number of question you answered correctly is '+ correct_num);
```

I expect the value of correct_num is 3 after I answer all the questions correctly. However, the value of correct_num displayed on the screen is still 0... I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: `player_ans.toLowerCase` should be `player_ans.toLowerCase()`

Comment: As mentioned above you have to add () to `toLowerCase` function call. And also I would advise you to check `if (player_ans)`, because if you will cancel prompt it will fails.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask how to detect the problem that I just made? In the console in Google DevTool, it does not spot my problem (i.e. missing parathesis)

Comment: @dganenco Sorry. I am not sure what you were saying. Would you mind giving me an example code?

Comment: @JackyChau it's something you have to check. [`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is a method, so it needs to be executed. In general, anything that requires an *operation* would likely be a method and require execution via `()`. In this case you need to *transform* a string into lowercase. While a static lookup that doesn't need to do any processing would be a property, for example `.length` simply gives you the size of a string.

Comment: I see. But why some errors can be spotted by console directly when I pressed the console.log but sometimes some errors like this will not be spotted? Is it because this mistake does not entirely affect the program to run so the console in googleDov does not spot it directly?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Forget what I asked about console. I have just found that the console did spot out my problem after I typed and submitted answer in the prompt. But I remember some issues were spotted immediately when I opened the console . Then, now I know how the debugging works. Thanks.

Comment: @JackyChau in this case, this is not an *error*. Doing `player_ans.toLowerCase` will return the *function* itself, which is a valid value. However the function is not equal to some string, hence the equality check will always fail. Again, not an *error*. You can use `console.log()` to check what the value of various things are, for example you can do `console.log(player_ans.toLowerCase)` which will print the function itself, rather than just the text but in lowercase. You can also use a debugger to step through the code and examine each expression or call.

Answer (score 1):

`toLowerCase` is a function so use it as  `toLowerCase()`

```js
var exercise= [ 
             ['What is the first name of our professor in this course?', 'cecilia'],
              ['What is the last name of our prof in this coursrs?', 'chan'],
              ['Which language is the most popular one in the world?', 'javascript']
]; 
var player_ans;
var correct_num=0;
    for(var i=0; i<exercise.length; i++){
       player_ans= prompt(exercise[i][0]); 
       
       if(player_ans.toLowerCase() === exercise[i][1])
         { correct_num+= 1;
         console.log(player_ans)
          }
     }
 document.write('The number of question you answered correctly is '+ correct_num);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask how to detect the problem that I just made? In the console in Google DevTool, it does not spot my problem (i.e. missing parathesis)

Comment: Use an editor instead of notepad. Preferably VS Code

Answer (score 1):

prompt() returns the second variable you pass into it.
And you should have toLowerCase() for the comparison.

```
player_ans= prompt(exercise[i][0],exercise[i][1]);       
if(player_ans.toLowerCase() === exercise[i][1].toLowerCase())
{ 
   correct_num+= 1;
   console.log(player_ans)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

toLowerCase is function, that's a problem, you should have this code>

```
    var exercise= [ 
             ['What is the first name of our professor in this course?', 'cecilia'],
              ['What is the last name of our prof in this coursrs?', 'chan'],
              ['Which language is the most popular one in the world?', 'javascript']
]; 
var player_ans;
var correct_num=0;
    for(var i=0; i<exercise.length; i++){
       player_ans= prompt(exercise[i][0]);  

       if(player_ans.toLowerCase() === exercise[i][1])
         { correct_num+= 1; 
          }
     }
 document.write('The number of question you answered correctly is '+ correct_num);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask how to detect the problem that I just made? In the console in Google DevTool, it does not spot my problem (i.e. missing parathesis)

Comment: @JackyChau Well, you should debug your code, for example, you can use console.log and see console.log(player_ans.toLowerCase), it will throw an error

Comment: I see. But before I  did not know the problem is on my toLowerCase, then do you mean I need to debug each line of my code in console.log? But if there are so many lines in my code, is there a more convenient way? I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Forget what I asked about console. I have just found that the console did spot out my problem after I typed and submitted answer in the prompt. But I remember some issues were spotted immediately when I opened the console . Then, now I know how the debugging works. Thanks.